# What becomes of the massive clouds expelled from Quasars?

Tags: energy, space, galaxies

What becomes of the massive clouds expelled from Quasar jets? Do they simply disperse into intergalactic diffuse clouds? Or do they on occasion have enough gravity to hold together and or collapse? If they collapse, what becomes of them?

Does anybody else get the impression from the following pictures that the clouds hold together? [Quasar jet cloud image Google search](https://www.google.com.au/search?q=quasar%20jets%20clouds&rlz=1C1GGGE___AU509AU510&espv=210&es_sm=93&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ei=IL0EU_zjEcLroAT9w4LwBQ&ved=0CAkQ_AUoAQ&biw=1366&bih=667)

Answer (score 2):

You don't cite a source for the matter ejected by quasars, but I'd guess you're thinking of the jets that are typically expelled from the poles. The answer is that if the jets have enough energy they do indeed disperse into intergalactic space, and space is indeed full of aimlessly drifting intergalactic clouds. For example [see this article](http://www.space.com/2625-space-dust-pervasive-thought.html), or Googling will find you many similar articles.

Comment: Thank you once again John. Yes I do refer to clouds ejected from Quasar jets. And you may be right, the clouds may simply disperse in space. Much of the dust referred to is in immediate proximity of galaxies, and their source theorized to be supernova and or stellar wind. But there are dust clouds further afield. These clouds are very diffuse, and I couldn't find reference to quasars being a source. But perhaps that's the simple truth. I would like to find visual evidence quasar clouds disperse. I'll alter my question

Comment: @Steve: For visual evidence that the jets from quasars disperse see [this image](http://images.nrao.edu/132) or many others like it found by Googling something like *quasar jets*.

Comment: It could easily be true that the clouds disperse, however those images can be interpreted two ways. Take this image for example, which implies the clouds maybe collapsing, becoming denser at their center. http://www.cv.nrao.edu/~abridle/images/3c219lonopt_large.jpg Certainly not proof, but suggestive. And another very loose circumstantial case can be made concerning the quasar clouds are a very similar size to the defuse dust clouds that encapsulate many galaxies. But like I said, very circumstantial.

Comment: You have definitely given me pause, however I'm not completely over your side of the fence yet. Clearly I'm a little bias, but I'll try to keep that in check while I continue investigating. I know this must seam pretty silly to some